# How to connect button actions with surfaceview canvas drawables?

Tags: android, button, canvas, drawable, surfaceview

My problem is that I don't know how to change position of a canvas drawable on click of
my button that it's located in the main activity and not to surfaceview so the code to work should be on surfaceview here is what I've got

```
public class JumpOnClick extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

DrawingSurface ds;
FrameLayout frm;
Button btnC;
int color=0xfff00000;
@Override



 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
ds=new DrawingSurface(this);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_jump_on_click);


frm=(FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.frameLayout);
frm.addView(ds);
btnC=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonColor);



btnC.setOnClickListener(this);

}



@Override

public void onClick(View v) {


//   how to connect  actions in here for my sprites on my surfaceview

// for example         AnimatedSprite a = new AnimatedSprite();             
//      if(b == null)
//b=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(res.openRawResource(R.drawable.explosion));          
//                   a.Initialize(b, 120, 159, 7, 20, true);
//                  mSprites.add(a);


}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly,
define two static float variables in your surfaceview class respectively x and y, and when you do your drawing in your surfaceview just use this variables as position parameters in your surfaceview's draw method. And then back in your activity in your onClick method of the button just change these x,y variables, as you can access them without any need to create object.

Comment: HI I've implemented the x and y variables as static float X =200; static float Y = 400;  It seems your solution doesn't work on my onclick button. I've implemented on touch on my surfaceview and works fine but the button on my main activity doesn't,there must be a way to reference my x and y variables

Comment: the reason why your mainactivity button not working is; because surfaceholder is the main focus of screen, so it receives all user touch. You should create a button implementation yourself at SurfaceView or wherever you use touchlistener :)
e.g assume you have a button on (30,40) with width and height of (100,100) then on your on touch method write a code like this

    float x=30, y=40, width=100, height=100;
    if(userinput.x>x && userinput.x<(x+width) && userinput.y>y &&   
       userinput.y<(y+height))
     {
       // your button is clicked, do some action here
     }

Comment: userinput cannot be resolved to a variable error, please make another effort to help me

Comment: make sure you get user input by using touchlistener, and then onTouchEvent() you can put the code i wrote above to make button work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need to add layout rules to your button to place it in the Surfaceview (Actually a button cant be added to a SurfaceView, you need to create an illusion with a Layout in your Activity and place the button to this Layout).

You can check this simple solution at this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8qE9TQjQ5no&t=31s

that is placing buttons to a SurfaceView at the top and bottom using a Relativelayout. My opinion is with that technique you wont need the ontouchevent method neither the x,y position, you will need that if you create a button in the ondraw method (then wont be a button but a bitmap image)...My opinion is to stick with the first solution if the position is the problem so it can act as a button with the onclicklistener.